# azure container service creating issue

Tags: azure-aks

I am trying to bring up K8s Cluster in Azure. This is the error I am getting:

> az aks create --resource-group upf-infra-ResourceGroup --name upf-infra-K8sCluster-1 --node-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys
>   Deployment failed. Correlation ID: d90bed78-075f-4a07-81c0-271dac75e0ca. PutControlPlane error

Comment: This looks very much like https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/pull/7442, which should have been fixed. Does the problem still remain?

Answer (score 0):

Include kubernetes version when creating your cluster.
Ex: az aks create --resource-group  --name  --node-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys --kubernetes-version 1.8.7

https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/284